# Given a map $T(x) = 2 \sin(x)$, find the fixed point on $[\pi/2,\pi]$

Tags: real-analysis, banach-fixed-point, fixed-point-iteration

Given a map $T(x) = 2 \sin(x)$, find a fixed point (It is on $(\frac{\pi}{2}, \pi)$).

Note that $T(x)$ is a contraction on $(\frac{\pi}{3}, 2\frac{\pi}{3})$.
By Banach contraction principle, $T^n(x_0)$ converges to $x^*$ .

How can we approximate $x^*$ up to $4$ decimal places?

I set $x_0 = \frac{\pi}{3}$ and repeat the process initiated by $T(x_0)=2\sin(\frac{\pi}{3})$, and continue this way.

But it won't give $x^*$.

Comment: Why start with $\pi/3$? It's not in your interval.

Comment: I am aware of it now. I'll correct it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Starting with $\pi/3$ will converge to the fixed point at $x = 0$. Draw the picture for the iterates to makes sure that you understand what's going on here. It's relevant that the function is increasing on $[0, \pi/2]$, and lies strictly above the line $y = x$ here.

Starting with $\pi/2$ will converge to a fixed point near $1.8955$ (accurate to $4$ places) after about $20$ iterations.